# find string from delimited values from delimited values (Oracle PL-SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can write a query for Oracle database such that I can find a comma delimited list of values from a column that contains comma delimited list of values. The :parameter passed to sql statement is also a comma delimited values that user selected.

For e.g
We have a column in tables that contains

1 | 'A','B','C'

2 | 'C','A'

3 | 'A','B'

on the web application interface we have multi select box that shows
A
B
C
and allows user to to select one or more items.

I want rows 1 and 2 to show up if they select A and B, If they select A only the all three should show up b/c all rows 1 to 3 have 'A' value in it.

Comment: CSV lists in table columns is indicative of a poor design. Can you shoot the analyst?

Comment: You mention "on the web application interface". Php,Java,.NET, ruby can handle this design more easily.

Comment: DCookie, I will have to do that, I felt the same this morning :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example will hopefully help and it matches the values irrespective of which order they appear in the string in the DB record.

Create example table:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(val VARCHAR2(100));
```

Insert records:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('1|''A'',''B'',''C''');

INSERT INTO t VALUES
('2|''C'',''A''');

INSERT INTO t VALUES
('3|''A'',''B''');
```

Check values:

```
SELECT * FROM t;
```

> ```
> 1|'A','B','C'
> 2|'C','A'    
> 3|'A','B'
> ```

Check solution for 'A':

```
SELECT val
  FROM t
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(val, '(A)');
```

> ```
> 1|'A','B','C'   
> 2|'C','A'      
> 3|'A','B'
> ```

Check solution for A and B

```
SELECT val
  FROM t
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(val, '(A|B).*(A|B)');
```

> ```
> 1|'A','B','C'
> 3|'A','B'
> ```

If you want to make sure the `1|` part of the result isn't matched by anything then you could query using:

```
SELECT val
  FROM t
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(val, '(.\|.*)(A)');
```

and

```
SELECT val
  FROM t
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(val, '(.\|.*)(A|B).*(A|B)');
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a where clause with varying number of bind values, depending on the number of selected options:

```
TEST@PRJ> create table t (c varchar2(100));
TEST@PRJ> insert into t values ('2 | ''C'',''A''');
TEST@PRJ> insert into t values ('3 | ''A'',''B''');
TEST@PRJ> select * from t where c like '%''A''%' and c like '%''B''%';

C
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 'A','B','C'
3 | 'A','B'

TEST@PRJ> select * from t where c like '%''A''%';

C
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 'A','B','C'
2 | 'C','A'
3 | 'A','B'
```

If the values are stored in order you could use a single bind value:

```
TEST@PRJ> select * from t where c like '%''A''%''B''%';

C
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 'A','B','C'
3 | 'A','B'
```